# Datetimepicker in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with datetimepicker in the bootstrap

when I click the text the date time does not appear

here is the code :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm4.aspx.cs" Inherits="iFassen_Force_de_vente.WebForm4" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/Jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Bootstrap datepicker will appear when we click on the calendar icon. You want to appear on text focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the picker to display when clicking the textbox, I think you should bind it to the textbox. Here is an example:

```js
$(function () {$('#txtDateTime').datetimepicker({sideBySide: true});$('#txtDate').datetimepicker({format: 'hh:mm A'});$('#txtTime').datetimepicker({format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'});});
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>
  
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="TestDateTimePicker2.aspx" id="form1" style="position:relative">
        <input name="txtDateTime" type="text" id="txtDateTime" class="m-wrap span12 date form_datetime"/>
         <input name="txtDate" type="text" id="txtDate" class="m-wrap span12 date form_datetime"/>
         <input name="txtTime" type="text" id="txtTime" class="m-wrap span12 date form_datetime"/>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```